# Magento 1.9.1.1 Coupon Code is Not Valid

Tags: magento, e-commerce, coupon

I am using Magento version 1.9.1.1.

I am trying to set-up a discount coupon code for some customers who will be able to order 6 items completely free of charge.But for some reason, I keep getting "Coupon code "XYZ" is not valid.
I investigated,but unable to found what the problem is.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: what are your conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had some other Shopping Cart Rule active and I had set the "Stop Further Rules Processing" to Yes for that rule. So that it was blocking the other rule.
I was able to solve the issue by setting the priority for both the rules and set the "Stop Further Rules Processing" to No. Now the coupon code is working fine.

Comment: You saved my day and my mental health.

Answer (score 0):

From promotion tab check catalog tab and click on apply promotions. After that check condition of rule or coupon code you have created. After then do indexing. Now it should work...

Best of Luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue so I just deleted that rule and create new same rule it work fine.